# Theorem of Generalization- Logic

Tags: logic

I'm an undergraduate student and I have take a Mathematical Logic course this semester.
I just read about the theorem of generalization in constants and I have (maybe a silly one) question.
Why the hypothesis that symbol c does not occur in any wffs in Γ is essential?
Could someone give me an example that the theorem will not work without it?
Thanks you!

Comment: Consider $\Gamma = \{ 0 \le 1 \}$ and consider the (wrong) application of Gen : $0 \le 1 \vdash \forall x \ (x \le 1)$. Thus, by $\to$-intro (or *Deduction Th*) : $\vdash (0 \le 1) \to \forall x \ (x \le 1)$.

Comment: ok it was very helpful! And how about the theorem that says that if ΓUφ^χ_c |- ψ and c does not occur in any wffs in Γ then ΓU(EXISTS)χ(φ) |- ψ ?  What is the counterexample for that?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose I know that Charlie is a dog, and so I have as a premise $Dog(c)$.

Now, if the universal generalization rule would not mandate that the symbol from which we generalize is a 'new' symbol, then we can use the premise to conclude $\forall x Dog(x)$, i.e. *everything* is a dog!  Clearly we should not be able to infer that just because Charlie is a dog.

This is why we mandate the constant to be a 'new' constant.  It should be a temporary name that we use to denote "some arbitrary object from our domain ... let's call it $c$" ... but that of course means that $c$ should not denote some specific individual as was the case with Charlie.

Answer (score 0):

(Rule EI - Existential Instantiation) If Γ;αxc⊢β where the constant symbol c does not occur in any wffs in Γ , α or β , then Γ;∃xα⊢β (and there is a deduction of β from Γ;∃xα that does not use c ).